# Skyrim Creation Kit with Xbox 360

Tags: module, xbox360

I posted this on the Bethesda forums, but the thread was locked before I could get responses (the moderator said it wouldn't happen, here's a link to the thread: http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1350734-creation-kit-xbox/ ).
I'm posting it here, since this is a more programming oriented community, so I was hoping for constructive feedback on the plausibility.
 Here is the question:

**EDIT**: I just posted this question on stackexchange. If you're interested see this thread: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24249/skyrim-creation-kit-with-xbox-360

---

> I'm thinking about buying the PC version of Skyrim to get the Creation
>   Kit (I already own a copy for the Xbox). I have read the faq and
>   scoured plenty of forums to see if there was some way to mod Skyrim
>   for a console (Xbox 360, in particular), but they are generally coming
>   up negative.
>
> I realize the CreationKit is on the PC, but I was wondering if there
>   was a way to set up the '.esp' (hopefully I'm interpreting this
>   correctly) files to be placed on the Xbox 360 file system in a similar
>   manner to how game add-ons are downloaded from the Xbox Live
>   Marketplace.
>
> I believe it is possible to transfer saves between the console and the
>   PC (e.g. google: 'skyrim mod xbox360'), but these are referencing
>   items that already exist in the game (e.g. a console command for
>   maximum carry weight does not require reference to new animations or
>   models).
>
> It would probably be easier if one could navigate through the xbox's
>   file system to see where the games' files are placed, but with the
>   current setup, the file system is abstracted away.
>
> Any help or insight on the matter would be much appreciated. I would
>   love to work on a project that would make it possible to let console
>   gamers experience and enjoy all the great mods available to the PC
>   community.

---

Comment: Hmm.. or can anyone point me in the direction of a forum or website that might be relevant?

Comment: You'll probably get a better response on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Cool, I post this on there. Thanks!